# Map Return NULL

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

**When Application run always return NULL Exception**
    `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback)' on a null object reference`

```
     if (map == null) {
    MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googlemap) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            map=googlemap;
           // startMap();
        }
    });
}
```

**Xml Code is here where i used Map ***

```
                <fragment
                    android:id="@+id/map"
                    class="com.shahi.driver.locationfiles.TouchableMapFragment"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

Comment: map is global/final ?

Comment: public static GoogleMap map;

Comment: @RishabhDugar
public static GoogleMap map

Comment: can you put Log statement in your TODO and check

Comment: post your XML file

Comment: post your XML code

Comment: @nitinkumarp i post

Comment: Maybe you should use getSupportFragmentManager instead of getFragmentManager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **class** will be:

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    @Override
        protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);
            try {
                // Loading map
               MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
                mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
                mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        }

    @Override
        public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
            final LatLng current_position = new LatLng(your_latitude, your_longitude);
            MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(current_position).title("Your Address").snippet("Anything");
            googleMap.addMarker(marker);
            googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(current_position, 12));
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(true);
            googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
    }
```

and **your_layout.xml** will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
 <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng location = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location ).title("Marker in location "));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));

}
```

}

Then your xml:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.polaris.project_x.MapsActivity" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see you have used custom Map Fragment on your XML code. By searching through its name I chanced upon its code on GitHub.

The issue on your code is that you are trying to get MapFragment from your layout but your Custom Map code is extending SupportMapFragment.

So to make your code work change your MapFragment to SupportMapFragment.

```
 SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager()
        .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
```

Also if your BaseActivity is extending AppCompatActivity then use getSupportFragmentManager() instead of getFragmentManager().